# Суффиксы прилагательных

Tags: орфография

О или Е пишется в суффиксах прилагательных после шипящих?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

О пишется в суффиксах "-ов-" или "-он-" под ударением.
Например: *грош**ов**ый, смеш**он**.*

Answer (score 0):

Под ударением о, без ударания - е: ситцевый, грушевый. То же правило касается и суффиксов существительных, и окончаний существительных и прилагательных. Девчонка - реченька. Большого - большего. Лапшой - кольцом. Правило касается не только шипящих, но и Ц.

Comment: НЕТ В РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ СЛОВА "ГРУШОВЫЙ"!!

Comment: но грушевый - то точно есть!